# How to configure log4j for a Spark program running inside of Intellij?

Tags: apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-sql

I've tried all possible suggestion on google but I still get spark log with INFO level which is too verbose.

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, LogManager, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object  tmp {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val spark =  SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")

    LogManager.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger()
    rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.OFF)

    spark.read.json("/home/white/wk/tmp/people.json").show
  }
}
```

Comment: Try putting the statement: `Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.OFF)` before initializing the spark session.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a `log4j.properties` file you might want to use:

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy tpInputOf the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#

# Set everything to be logged to the console
log4j.rootCategory=WARN, console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.target=System.err
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %p %c{1}: %m%n

# Set the default spark-shell log level to WARN. When running the spark-shell, the
# log level for this class is used to overwrite the root logger's log level, so that
# the user can have different defaults for the shell and regular Spark apps.
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.Main=WARN

# Settings to quiet third party logs that are too verbose
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty=WARN
log4j.logger.org.spark_project.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$exprTyper=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$SparkILoopInterpreter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.parquet=ERROR
log4j.logger.parquet=ERROR

# SPARK-9183: Settings to avoid annoying messages when looking up nonexistent UDFs in SparkSQL with Hive support
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler=FATAL
log4j.logger.org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionRegistry=ERROR
```

It sets the `log4j.rootCategory` to `WARN`. You can use `ERROR` if you want less messages. Put this file in the root of your classpath. If you have a Maven project, that would be `src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set log level on SparkContext

sc.setLogLevel("ERROR")

Answer (score 1):

An important part of any application is the underlying log system we incorporate into it. Logs are not only for debugging and traceability but also for business intelligence. Building a robust logging system within our apps could be used as a great insight into the business problems we are solving.

Log4j in Apache Spark
Spark uses log4j as the standard library for its own logging. Everything that happens inside Spark gets logged to the shell console and to the configured underlying storage. Spark also provides a template for app writers so we could use the same_log4j_ libraries to add whatever messages we want to the existing and in-place implementation of logging in Spark.

Configuring Log4j
Under the _SPARK_HOME/conf_ folder, there is_log4j.properties.template_ file which serves as a starting point for our own logging system.

Based on this file, we created the log4j.properties file and put it under the same directory.

```
log4j.properties looks like follows:

log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.myConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d [%t] %-5p %c - %m%n

log4j.appender.RollingAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.File=/var/log/spark.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n

log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.File=/var/log/sparkU.log
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.RollingAppenderU.layout.ConversionPattern=[%p] %d %c %M - %m%n
```

By default, everything goes to console and file

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, RollingAppender, myConsoleAppender
```

My custom logging goes to another file

```
log4j.logger.myLogger=INFO, RollingAppenderU
```

The noisier spark logs go to file only

```
log4j.logger.spark.storage=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.storage=false
log4j.logger.spark.scheduler=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.scheduler=false
log4j.logger.spark.CacheTracker=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.CacheTracker=false
log4j.logger.spark.CacheTrackerActor=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.CacheTrackerActor=false
log4j.logger.spark.MapOutputTrackerActor=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivity.spark.MapOutputTrackerActor=false
log4j.logger.spark.MapOutputTracker=INFO, RollingAppender
log4j.additivty.spark.MapOutputTracker=false
```

Basically, we want to hide all logs Spark generates so we don’t have to deal with them in the shell. We redirect them to be logged in the file system. On the other hand, we want our own logs to be logged in the shell and a separate file so they don’t get mixed up with the ones from Spark. From here, we will point Splunk to the files where our own logs are which in this particular case is_/var/log/sparkU.log._

This (log4j.properties) file is picked up by Spark when the application starts so we don’t have to do anything aside of placing it in the mentioned location.

Writing Our Own Logs
Now that we have configured the components that Spark requires in order to manage our logs, we just need to start writing logs within our apps.

In order to show how this is done, let’s write a small app that helps us in the demonstration.

Our App:

```
object app {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val log = LogManager.getRootLogger
log.setLevel(Level.WARN)

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("demo-app")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

log.warn("Hello demo")

val data = sc.parallelize(1 to 100000)

log.warn("I am done")
}
}
```

Running this Spark app will demonstrate that our log system works. We will be able to see how _Hello demo _and I am done messages being logged in the shell and in the file system while the Spark logs will only go to the file system.

So far, everything seems easy, yet there is a problem we haven’t mentioned.

The class org.apache.log4j.Logger is not serializable which implies we cannot use it inside a closure while doing operations on some parts of the Spark API.

For example, if we do in our app:

```
val log = LogManager.getRootLogger
val data = sc.parallelize(1 to 100000)

data.map { value =>
log.info(value)
value.toString
}
```

This will fail when running on Spark. Spark complaints that the_log_ object is not Serializable so it cannot be sent over the network to the Spark workers.

This problem is actually easy to solve. Let’s create a class that does something to our data set while doing a lot of logging.

```
class Mapper(n: Int) extends Serializable{
@transient lazy val log = org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("myLogger")

def doSomeMappingOnDataSetAndLogIt(rdd: RDD[Int]): RDD[String] =
rdd.map{ i =>
log.warn("mapping: " + i)
(i + n).toString
}
}
```

The mapper receives an _RDD[Int] _and returns an RDD[String] and it also logs what value it's being mapped. In this case, noted how the_log_ object has been marked as @transient which allows the serialization system to ignore the log object. Now, Mapper is being serialized and sent to each worker but the log object is being resolved when it is needed in the worker, solving our problem.

Another solution is to wrap the log object into an _object_construct and use it all over the place. We rather have a log within the class we are going to use it, but the alternative is also valid.

At this point, our entire app looks like follows:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, LogManager, PropertyConfigurator}
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

class Mapper(n: Int) extends Serializable{
@transient lazy val log = org.apache.log4j.LogManager.getLogger("myLogger")
def doSomeMappingOnDataSetAndLogIt(rdd: RDD[Int]): RDD[String] =
rdd.map{ i =>
log.warn("mapping: " + i)
(i + n).toString
}
}
object Mapper {
def apply(n: Int): Mapper = new Mapper(n)
}
object app {
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val log = LogManager.getRootLogger
log.setLevel(Level.WARN)
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("demo-app")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

log.warn("Hello demo")

val data = sc.parallelize(1 to 100000)
val mapper = Mapper(1)
val other = mapper.doSomeMappingOnDataSetAndLogIt(data)
other.collect()

log.warn("I am done")
}
}
```

Conclusions
Our logs are now being shown in the shell and also stored in their own files. Spark logs are being hidden from the shell and is logged into their own file. We also solved the serialization problem that appears when trying to log in to different workers.

We now can build more robust BI systems based on our own Spark logs as we do with other non distributed systems and applications we have today. Business Intelligence is for us a very big deal and having the right insights is always nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `log4j.properties` file to the classpath with the `rootLogger` level set to `FATAL` or `OFF`.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for `Intellij` the location is `${project.home}/src/test/resources/log4j.properties` . We can see that `Intellij` copies this to the `test-classes` directory:

```
$find /git/forecast-ml/ -name log4j.properties
/git/forecast-ml.yuan//src/test/resources/log4j.properties
/git/forecast-ml.yuan/target/scala-2.11/test-classes/log4j.properties
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using slf4j in your application you can use this XML to restrict all the logs

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="com.ning.http.client" level="ERROR"/>
</configuration>
```